# copy to clipboard with left click

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Suppose I have a webpage with this content:

```
<h1 id="foo"> Some string </h1>
```

Now I want to to copy `Some string` to clipboard. But the conditions are:

- My webpage (app) is mouse oriented so I don't want to let the users to touch the keyboard.
- Right click is already engaged in another task, so I can't use right.

The only way is to hover over the `<h1>` with `id="foo"` and press left mouse button.

I googled it and found a JavaScript way to do this. But soon I knew that that's not cross browser. So, is there is way to copy text on left click of the hovered `h1`.

Comment: @GregHewgill Didn't you see that I have said pure JavaScript are not cross browser and I don't want it? How can this be duplicate.

Comment: Did you read the answers to that question? The answers all talk about cross-browser solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Using an adobe flash call is probably your best bet.

I have used this one with marginal success: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

If the java method is not acceptable because it is not cross browser compatible I am not even going to suggest some decrepit (and probably security hole causing) Active X component which would effectively be IE only (with few exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

Started the search here and found http://www.steamdev.com/zclip

---

This plugin is cross-compatible with all browsers and works well:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard